# Mapping Untyped Lisp data into a typed binary format for use in compiled functions

Tags: data-structures, haskell, lisp, scheme, llvm

**Background**: I'm writing a toy Lisp (Scheme) interpreter in Haskell. I'm at the point where I would like to be able to compile code using LLVM.  I've spent a couple days dreaming up various ways of feeding untyped Lisp values into compiled functions that expect to know the format of the data coming at them.  It occurs to me that I am not the first person to need to solve this problem.

**Question**: What are some historically successful ways of mapping untyped data into an efficient binary format.

**Addendum**: In point of fact, I do know which of about a dozen different types the data is, I just don't know which one might be sent to the function at compile time.  The function itself needs a way to determine what it got.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean, "I just don't know which [type] might be sent to the function at *runtime*"? It's not that the data isn't typed; certainly `1` and `'()` have different types. Rather, the data is not statically typed, i.e., it's not known at compile time what the type of a given variable will be. This is called [dynamic typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Dynamic_typing).

You're right that you're not the first person to need to solve this problem. The canonical solution is to *tag* each runtime value with its type. For example, if you have a dozen types, number them like so:

- 0 = integer
- 1 = `cons` pair
- 2 = vector
- etc.

Once you've done this, reserve the first four bits of each word for the tag. Then, every time two objects get passed in to `+`, first you perform a simple bit mask to verify that both objects' first four bits are 0b0000, i.e., that they are both integers. If they are not, you jump to an error message; otherwise, you proceed with the addition, and make sure that the result is also tagged accordingly.

This technique essentially makes each runtime value a manually-[tagged union](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union), which should be familiar to you if you've used C. In fact, it's also just like a Haskell data type, except that in Haskell the taggedness is much more abstract.

I'm guessing that you're familiar with pointers if you're trying to write a Scheme compiler. To avoid limiting your usable memory space, it may be more sensical to use the bottom (least significant) four bits, rather than the top ones. Better yet, because aligned dword pointers already have three meaningless bits at the bottom, you can simply co-opt those bits for your tag, as long as you dereference the actual address, rather than the tagged one.

Does that help?

Comment: Using the low bits for tags (or at least for most tags) allows you to save some time when doing addition, as well. It can even allow you to extract one more bit, if you are careful about your lowtags (one lowtag that is 0..0 and one that is 1..0 for even and odd fixnums).

Answer (score 2):

Your default solution should be a simple tagged union. If you want to narrow your typing down to more specific types, you can do it - but it won't be that "toy" any more. A thing to look at is called [abstract interpretation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_interpretation).

There are few successful implementations of such an optimisation, with [V8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V8_(JavaScript_engine)) being probably the most widespread. In the Scheme world, the most aggressively optimising implementation is [Stalin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stalin_(Scheme_implementation)).